# JS What's the fastest way to display one specific line of a list?

Tags: javascript, filter, split

In my Javascript code, I get one very long line as a string.
This one line only has around 65'000 letters. Example:

```
config=123&url=http://localhost/example&path_of_code=blablaba&link=kjslfdjs...
```

What I have to do is **replace all & with an break (\n) first** and then **pick only the line which starts with "path_of_code="**. This line I have to write in a variable.

The part with replace & with an break (\n) I already get it, but the second task I didn't.

```
    var obj = document.getElementById('div_content');
    var contentJS= obj.value;
    var splittedResult;
    splittedResult = contentJS.replace(/&/g, '\n');
```

What is the fastest way to do it? Please note, the list is usually very long.

Comment: _" replace all & with an break (\n) first"_ - Why? This operation on its own doesn't make much sense or would in any way make the task even easier.

Comment: Good point, but I have to. Reason: I have to display it, even I am working only with one element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to extract the text after `&path_of_code=` up until either the end of the string or the next `&`. That's easily done with a regular expression using a capture group, then using the value of that capture group:

```
var rex = /&path_of_code=([^&]+)/;
var match = rex.exec(theString);
if (match) {
    var text = match[1];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var theString = "config=123&url=http://localhost/example&path_of_code=blablaba&link=kjslfdjs...";
var rex = /&path_of_code=([^&]+)/;
var match = rex.exec(theString);
if (match) {
    var text = match[1];
    console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but how can I handle, if there are two "path_of_code" ? If there are two of them, I have to work with both of them. but sparatly. I think the best way would be, write the result into an array, what do you think?

Comment: @EmbaBakar - If you add a `g` flag to the regex, you can call `exec` again on the same string to get the next occurrence. So you could loop until `exec` returns `null` to get all the occurrences. What you do with each occurrence is up to you: Process it as you go through the string, or store them in an array and process them afterward, or... It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

> > but the second task I didn't.

You can use `filter()` and `startsWith()`

```
splittedResult = splittedResult.filter(i => i.startsWith('path_of_code='));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```js
var contentJS= "123&url=http://localhost/example&path_of_code=blablaba&link=kjslfdjs...";

var index = contentJS.indexOf("&path_of_code"),
    substr = contentJS.substr(index+1),
    res = substr.substr(0, substr.indexOf("&"));

console.log(res)
```